# Http 403 error in Microsoft edge

Tags: iis

I was getting "HTTP 403 error Microsoft Edge can’t get to this page", while launching an application from IIS in Windows 10. Please suggest a solution for this.

thanks

Comment: You haven't exactly given us much to work with here. What application? What is it supposed to do? Who made it?

Comment: trying to launch a web application installed on IIS , developed for my own practice.

Comment: That comment gave us, like, literally zero extra information. Keep going.

Comment: I am kind of newbie with IIS, so i thought to kick off the learning by installing a default asp.net web application developed in visual studio 2010. For installation process, i have published the web app to a folder created by me under WWWroot in inetpub. Upon refresh the Default web site in IIS, i could able to see my folder i added. Using right click, i have converted to application. When i tried to browse it, i got the above error.

Answer (score 1):

If all permissions are set and even though your website shows 403 forbidden, most likely the default page is not set for your website. With IIS, you can configure the default document as follows.

1. Connect to IIS.
2. Expand the sites and select the desired website.
3. From right hand side feature view, click on Default Document.
4. Set your desire default page and save the settings.

While you browse any website, IIS searches for the default page to be displayed. If the first default document is not available, IIS will look for the next default page from the list. When IIS is unable to find any match and directory listing is enabled for that particular website, IIS will show you the list of folders. If directory listing is disabled, IIS will return an HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden message to the browser.

Comment: will give a try today.

Comment: I looked into it, i was able to see the default document. Still getting the same error. And this started to happening since from i have installed windows 10.0.

Comment: Are you able to browse the page in other browsers you have like FireFox or Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If an empty application gives you a 403 I can think of two immediate reasons.

1. The permissions are wrong. You might need to give the application pool user (`IIS AppPool\NAMEOFAPPPOOL` with recommended configuration) read permission to the directory.
2. You don't have any content. If you try to access a directory in IIS you will get a 403. Add a file and try to access that directly, or a `Default.aspx` or `index.html` file to the directory you're trying to access.

Comment: Tried the first and even made sure i have content , still getting the same Issue. This started to happen after installing windows 10.0.